# jupyter notebookでのファイルの書き込みと読み込みは連続で行えないのでしょうか？

Tags: python3, jupyter-notebook

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
jupyter notebookでpythonの学習を始めて1ヶ月程度の者です。
現在ファイルの書き込み・読み込み方法まで進んだのですが、

jupyter notebookで

```
f = open(new_file.txt", "w+")   
a = "こんにちは。"
f.write(a)
f.close
```

と実行した直後に別のセルで

```
f = open(new_file.txt", "r+")   
s = f.read()
print(s)
f.close
```

と実行すると、

```
<function TextIOWrapper.close>
```

とだけ表示されて、ファイルの内容が表示されません。

一度ノートを閉じてから、再度ノートを開き上記のread()メソッドを使うと
正しく表示されました。

```
こんにちは。
<function TextIOWrapper.close>
```

これは、
「同じファイルに対して書き込みと読み込みを連続で行うことはできず、
読み込むためには一度閉じる必要がある」
という理解でよろしいのでしょうか。

ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f.close
```

これだとcloseされないです。closeメソッドオブジェクトを得るだけで、呼び出していません。
以下の様に書いてください。

```
f.close()
```